# jquery find method giving syntax error

Tags: jquery, html

I'm getting the error message in my console and I don't know why:

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: )

the file it points to is the jquery.js file, line 16.

Here's my code:

```
    var contact_number = $('#contact_details').val();
    var call_order = $('#call_order').val();
    var contact_type = $("#contact_types option:selected").val();

    //prevent the user from adding the exact same entry.  
   var result = $('#rule_summary tr').find('td:contains(' + contact_number + ')');
```

The offending line is apparently the last one... where I'm trying to call the find method.

**What I've tried so far:**

I've changed the last line so it uses another variable instead of "contact_number" and the error message goes away.  So, for example, I did this:

```
 var result = $('#rule_summary tr').find('td:contains(' + call_order + ')');
```

I also double checked that the element I'm saving as "contact_number" is real / legit.  In the console, I did this:

```
 $('#contact_details').val();
```

And it returns and empty set of quotes... which is what the value is on page load. 
When I fill in the text box with some garbage data and retry the console, it returns the correct results.  for example:

```
 $('#contact_details').val();
"asdfa"
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong... any suggestions would be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Look at the generated string (including the value of `contact_number`)

Comment: Perhaps you could accept my answer on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to quote the value you are searching for, try:

```
var result = $('#rule_summary tr').find('td:contains("' + contact_number + '")');
```

I guess call_order was numeric which is why it was ok without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var result = $('#rule_summary tr').find("td:contains('" + contact_number + "')");
```